# Rails jquery on change doesn't work

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I have simple script

```
 $ ->
  $('.check__form').on 'change', ->
    $('#filter_form').submit()
```

but it work only when i reload page twice,on first load it doesn't work

How to fix it? or any advices what could cause this strange behavior

Comment: Do you use Turbolink (default gem for rails 4)? How is this script fired? Turbolink prevents using some events like `DOMContentLoaded` or `jQuery.ready()`

Comment: @user3033467 without turbolink